# Tkinter - recenter widgets

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new using Tkinter. What I want to do is to recenter images after click event. I posted some images so you guys can have an idea what I mean:

[image]

The gray background represent the main window (root frame) and small squares represent images. After I click on the yellow square, the yellow square move the center of the frame and other line up squares recenter. Then I make a click on the green square and happens the following:

[image]

Green square move to the center of the frame and the remaining squares recenter once again. Can someone please help me with this

Comment: What kind of help do you need? Perhaps if you can show us your existing code and what you've tried, we might be able to help.

Comment: Please, in addition to source code, edit your question and describe "What you want" and "What you get".